# Converted Vector to Raster file is Black and White in colour (GDAL Rasterize)

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, gdal-rasterize

```
def main1(shapefile):

    #making the shapefile as an object.
    input_shp = ogr.Open(shapefile)

    #getting layer information of shapefile.
    shp_layer = input_shp.GetLayer()

    #pixel_size determines the size of the new raster.
    #pixel_size is proportional to size of shapefile.
    pixel_size = 1

    #get extent values to set size of output raster.
    x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = shp_layer.GetExtent()

    #calculate size/resolution of the raster.
    x_res = int((x_max - x_min) / pixel_size)
    y_res = int((y_max - y_min) / pixel_size)

    #get GeoTiff driver by 
    image_type = 'GTiff'
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(image_type)

    #passing the filename, x and y direction resolution, no. of bands, new raster.
    new_raster = driver.Create(output_raster, x_res, y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)

    #transforms between pixel raster space to projection coordinate space.
    new_raster.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_size, 0, y_min, 0, pixel_size))

    #get required raster band.
    band = new_raster.GetRasterBand(1)

    #assign no data value to empty cells.
    no_data_value = -9999
    band.SetNoDataValue(no_data_value)
    band.FlushCache()

    #main conversion method
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(new_raster, [1], shp_layer, burn_values=[1])

    #adding a spatial reference
    new_rasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    new_rasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(2975)
    new_raster.SetProjection(new_rasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
    return gdal.Open(output_raster)
```

This is my code for converting vector .shp to raster .tif. It converts the shapefiles into .tif files BUT the output is only black and white in colour.

This is my input shapefile.

[image: input shapefile]

This is the output vector.

[image: output vector]

So what changes do I make in the code so that my output file has similar colour?

This is the current symbology properties:
[image: symbology1]

This is when I select multiband colour.
[image: symbology2]

Answer (score 2):

Imagine I have the following TIFF file:

[image]

To change its color, right click on the raster in the content panel > Properties...> Symbology and then choose *Paletted/Unique values* for Render Type. Then click on Classify and it will display all the unique values of your raster. I assume your unique value will be only `1` as it was the value you burned on the raster. Simply change its color and you are ready.

[image]

[image]

---

If you want to add the color from your Python script instead of changing the color of the TIFF file every time you open it in QGIS, consider adding a `ColorTable` to the file. You can try to add the following code to your function before you use the `FlushCache()` method on `band`.

```py
# create color table
colors = gdal.ColorTable()

# set color for the only value
colors.SetColorEntry(1, (225, 89, 137))

# set color table and color interpretation
band.SetRasterColorTable(colors)
band.SetRasterColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_PaletteIndex)
```